# ASmack Multiuser Chat room

Tags: android, classcastexception, asmack

I'm using Asmack API to create a Multiuser Chat room on android, I want to get all the hosted rooms by using

```
MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, service)
```

And keep getting Errors as follow:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2

I have search a lot but still didn't get any idea about how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated before I pull my hair out.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Call this function before login. This adds a lot of features asmack misses. I heard asmack 4+ doesn't require this. I am not sure.

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {

    // Private Data Storage
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",
            new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

    // Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",
                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TestClient",
                "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
    }

    // Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster",
            new RosterExchangeProvider());

    // Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",
            new MessageEventProvider());

    // Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    // XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",
            new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    // Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",
            new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

    // Service Discovery # Items
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
            new DiscoverItemsProvider());

    // Service Discovery # Info
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
            new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    // Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());

    // MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user",
            new MUCUserProvider());

    // MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",
            new MUCAdminProvider());

    // MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",
            new MUCOwnerProvider());

    // Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
            new DelayInformationProvider());

    // Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",
                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Not sure what's happening here.
    }

    // VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());

    // Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());

    // Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());

    // Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());

    // User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());

    // SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup",
            "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",
            new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

    // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/address",
            new MultipleAddressesProvider());

    // FileTransfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider(
            "query",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.provider.BytestreamsProvider());

    // Privacy
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());
}
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of code with basically no explanation. Please edit your answer to be more specific, and explain it clearly.